# Hyperscript button combined with fetch request

Tags: hyperscript

I want to make a button with the following behavior:

- after user click executing request to backend
- backend return link
- this link opened in new tab

I write this code

```
<button _="on click fetch '{% url 'some_api' movie.id %}' then
           log result then
           go to url result in new window">
Go to movie
</button>
```

but hyperscript do not understand that `result` it is variable and redirect directly on `http://localhost:8000/result`

Although `log result` command show correct link at console:

[image]

How I must change my code to make it working?

**UPD** movie.id is not is 2499491 in this example. Backend have a some logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `result` is a variable, you need to use string interpolation to render the url. Something like this should work:

```
go to url `${result}` in new window
```

`log` is showing the correct value, because it interprets the argument as expression ([ref](https://hyperscript.org/commands/log/)), so when providing variable it will display the value assigned, when providing list it will show as list object, etc.

`go` command expects string literals, not expression ([ref](https://hyperscript.org/commands/go/)), so everything you pass gets interpreted as string.

Comment: Thank you bro, it's working. But can you add more explanation, why `log result` works but not `go to url result`?